# For loop inside For Loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

For some reason this statement is skipping some data.Am I missing a
continue statement somewhere or something ?
Here is the code

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].SEC_TYPE == "MLEG") {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS.length; i++) {
      LEGS += '<tr class="MLEGS"><td class="orderFirst">' +
        data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS[i].SYMBOL +
        '</td><td>' + data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS[i].ACTION +
        '</td><td>' + data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS[i].QTY +
        '</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why in the world is it formatted like that? It looks like it's generated from a template file or something.

Comment: should you be using the i variable both times?

Answer (score 17):

Use a different variable on the inner loop, like `j` instead of `i`.

```
for (var i = 0, len=data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS.length; i < len; i++) {
    //...

   for (var j = 0; j < data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS.length; j++){
       //...
       data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS[j].SYMBOL +
```

Comment: That definitely works, but now the inner loop is only returning the first array  key in that object when there are 4. hmmm

Comment: @Bootleg: I would need to see your `data` to know why. Could you post it in the question?

Comment: @Bootleg: Any errors in the console? Hard to tell from an image what's going on. Could you posted your updated code in your question? Don't erase the original code. Just put the new code at the bottom.

Comment: @Bootleg: Ah those tricky CSS issues! Not a problem. Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: -1, should be "j < data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS.length" not " i < data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS.length"

Comment: @Greg: Thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to update that variable. But let me tell you something. You don't need to down-vote every time someone makes a minor mistake. I help to correct people's answers *all the time* without down-voting. I [corrected yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073514/how-to-remove-element-added-after-ajax-call-in-jquery/) the other day without down-voting you (or the others who had incorrect answers). In fact it's rare that I vote *anyone* down. If you look at my profile, you'll see that of my 3,434 votes, 96 are down. I'd rather help someone...

Comment: ...improve their answer than to do these drive-by down-votes.

Answer (score 3):

you are using "i" in your outer an inner loops. you need to use a different variable in the inner loop: i have used "inner" below as and example.

```
for (var i = 0, len=data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].SEC_TYPE=="MLEG"){
      for (var inner = 0; inner  < data.ORDER_STATUS[0].ORDERS[i].LEGS.length; inner ++) {
          // do something
      }
    }
  }
```