# How to remove element added after AJAX call in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm **trying to remove an HTML element added to my page upon return from an AJAX call.**
But jQuery seems to be unaware of such dynamically added elements. Any solutions?

**Context**:

- I'm building a simplistic shopping cart.
- When the user clicks the 'Add' button, I add the item in the database AND I want to display it onscreen without reloading the page.
- **But** since the user might click 'Add' multiple times for the same item
  in a shopping session, each time he clicks, I want to remove any
  lines of that item from the shopping cart DIV, and keep only the most
  recent one for that item.

Right now, it doesn't work so my HTML look like this after multiple adds:

```
<div id="CartList">
  <p id="Item_shirt7363">shirt7363</p>
  <p id="Item_shirt7363">shirt7363</p>
  <p id="Item_shirt7363">shirt7363</p>
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
function AddToCartClicked()
{
    item_code = $("#ItemCode").val();
    qty = $("#Qty").val(); 

    $.ajax
        (
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/_res/php/add-item.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: "puid=123&code=" + item_code + "&qty=" + qty,
                success: function(data)
                {       
                    // PROBLEM: First, remove any existing line with this ID
                    $("#Item_" + item_code).remove();               

                    // Write new line
                    newLine = "<p id='Item_" + item_code + "'>" + item_code + "</p>";                   

                    // Add the line in the HTML
                    $("#CartList").prepend(newLine);
                }
            }
        );

    return true;
}
```

I searched the forums and did not find a match for my question. Also, I'm new at this, so please assume stupidity. Thanks.

Comment: How about we assume temporary ignorance instead of stupidity?

Comment: Have you tried a `.replacewith()` instead of remove?

Comment: Can you console.log($("#Item_" + item_code).length) right before you're trying to remove it? Theoretically it will be 1.  Also, keep in mind that you might get a race condition with the latter ajax call returning before a former one.  It may overwrite the newer one with the old.  Gotta love async programming...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9J2JX/1/ works for me. must be something different?

Comment: Is there any more code that you can provide? Is this your actual code, or has it been modified?

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks** for all your help guys, it definitely helped me debug this!

In the end, the issue was that **some item codes had a period in them** ("shirt235.b") and jQuery has a problem retrieving that if the period is not escaped ([It's in the FAQ.](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F)).

I'm really sorry that I used a fictional example for simplicity, thinking it didn't matter what the item_code was... I've learned my lesson and will **only** post real-world code from now on! Please accept my apologies and thanks for your understanding.

Have a great week!

Answer (score 0):

I think val() only works for form elements, so you're not getting a valid return when calling it on a paragraph element; thus your selector is selecting nothing.

For debugging try outputting the val() result (item_code variable) and also see what the length of the selector is returning.

Comment: Dude that's his question. It should be removing the line, then re-adding it.

Comment: I don't think `.val()` is called on the `p` element. The `p` is coming from the HTML string being built from the *result* of the `.val()` call. Since the `p` elements are showing up with the `item_code`, it would seem as though that part is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work in most cases, but underneath there could be the following race condition:

Imagine if the user clicks add twice and then the the browser receives and runs both callback functions in parallel.

The callsbacks are not atomic, they could both have finished the "remove" function before either of them executes the "prepend" function.  In this case you would have two duplicates added.

One solution could be to use an ajax queue of some sort, or to use a variable to simulate a 'lock'.

Comment: The callbacks themselves must run synchronously. Once one begins, another will not be able to start until the previous returned. The only way the flow could be altered would be if the `.prepend()` itself was run *asynchronously*, like in a `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda a newbie too, but multiple identical ID's are bad. Try using .attr('data-id',item_code) for the selector, or create unique ids.

Comment: The multiple IDs are the issue OP is trying to solve. He's wondering why this line `$("#Item_" + item_code).remove();` isn't successfully removing the item with that ID before creating a new one.

Comment: Ah, I see. If worked properly, there would not be more than one element with that ID. So Greg's debugging suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's certainly something we're missing. Logging some values would definitely be helpful.