# For loops - looping inside loop, for getting the alphabets with their ascii value

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating alphabets using their ascii values.
I have got a for loop like this

```
var alpha = [];
for(var i=65;i<=90;i++){
    res = String.fromCharCode(i);
    alpha.push(res);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = alpha;

for(var i=65;i<=90;i++){
    res = String.fromCharCode(i);
    alpha.push(res);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = alpha;
```

So when I provide this I am getting an array with result [A.B,C....Z].
Now what I want is after pushing all the 26 alphabets I want [AA,AB,AC...AZ].
How is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For loop inside For Loop Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071818/for-loop-inside-for-loop-javascript)

Comment: base36 alternative `for (var i = 370; i < 396; i++) console.log(i.toString(36).toUpperCase());`

Comment: So you want 1 array that has 26 values - `AA - AZ` ?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Which output do you expect? `[A, B, ... Z]` and `[AA, AB, ... AZ]`? Or `[A...Z, AA, ... AZ]`? Or `[[A, ...Z],[AA, ...AZ]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are after:

```
var alpha = [];

for(var i=65;i<=90;i++){
  alpha.push(String.fromCharCode(i));
}


for(var i=65;i<=90;i++){
  var first = 'A';
  var next = String.fromCharCode(i);
  alpha.push(first + next);
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = alpha;
```

You can check out a running example here: https://jsfiddle.net/xr5dwLu1/1/

Comment: sorry i have edited the question please recheck!! thanks for your response

Comment: @Filype thanks this is what I wanted but a bit different i want the result in same array as that of the one i did. that is A to Z  and AA to AZ in the same array

Answer (score 1):

Just add another loop inside your initial loop:

```
for(var i=65;i<=90;i++){
    // add new loop with different variable for index (j)
    for(var j = 65; j <= 90; j++) {
        var res = String.fromCharCode(i) + String.fromCharCode(j);
        alpha.push(res);
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry i have edited the question please recheck!! thanks for your response

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. The sequence it generates is AA, AAB, AABC, AABCD... And I think @AyshaAzura is asking for AA, AB, AC, AD...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is! Try nesting loops:

```
for(var i=65;i<=90;i++){
    for(var j=65;j<=90;j++){
        res = String.fromCharCode(i) + String.fromCharCode(j);
        alpha.push(res);
    }
}
```

**Update:** After your edit, I looks like what you ask for is just:

```
for(var i=65;i<=90;i++) {
        res = 'A' + String.fromCharCode(i);
        alpha.push(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i have edited the question please recheck!! thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

ES6 solution with a generator.

```js
function* abc(pre){
    var i = 10;   
    while(i < 36) {
        yield pre + i.toString(36).toUpperCase();
        i++;
    }
}

let array = [...abc('A')]; 
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```